# How do I remove my KitchenAid attachment?

Tags: equipment, stand-mixer

My KitchenAid attachment appears to be stuck. I attempt to push up to remove the dough hook and it does not budge one bit. I am thinking I'm either doing something completely wrong or there's some way to get it unstuck!

Any advice?

Comment: I am trying out what they suggest in this video now:

   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE88Frx2Ysc


Will update with results.

Comment: The boiling water trick on the string and mechanism worked a treat for me - Thanks for the sound and solid advice

Answer (score 6):

It is usually stuck because of fresh or old food particles getting into the socket or release mechanism

The simplest way is to drizzle boiling water onto the release mechanism. A few large pours over some minutes may be required to soften and remove the food particles

A quick spray of silicone oil may be required after this as the boiling water removes all factory lubrication too

**Unplug the machine first!** and take great care not to get water into the motor or electronic parts. Position the device over a sink or bucket so that water will flow away from the motor and electronic parts

Answer (score 3):

My dough hook was almost impossible to remove.  I tried many things but pouring very hot water
over the the spring and shaft worked in a short time. Make sure it is unplugged and water does not get into the motor. It might take several attempts to free it. Clean the shaft  and the area of the hook where the shaft inserts. Apply some cooking oil to those areas after cleaning. You will have to lay the appliance on it's side to perform this procedure.

Answer (score 2):

had a stuck mixer attachment, 2mins under the hot tap worked, then I added vaseline to the top to make it easier to attach, I believe washing in dishwasher removed all grease from it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

KitchenAid recommends that you compress a warm, wet towel around the top of the attachment for 10 minutes. Reheat the towel and repeat for another couple of minutes. The warmth will cause the aluminum to expand, and with some wiggling, should allow you to release the attachment.